# Java Deallocation

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection, ram

I have a program that runs JavaFX with a ListView of objects of the Item Class. When the item is clicked, it pulls up a separate window to show the information of that object. Every time I close the item window and open up another one, it just adds used ram, and I am on a relatively tight system. How do I go about getting the Item and ItemWindow object to be de-referenced when the user clicks the red X?

My code in the ItemWindow class is as follows:

```
Parent root;
       Scene scene;
     stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
                System.out.println("UR tryna close meh!");
                item.close();
                stage.close();
                System.gc();
            }
     });
```

My the close() method in the Item class:

```
public void close() {
    date_purchased=null;
//      price_bought=(Double) null;
//      width=(Double) null;
//      length=(Double) null;
//      item_num=(Long) null;
    palette=null;
    label=null;
    designer=null;
    care=null;
    name=null;
    other=null;
    picURL=null;
    placeBought=null;
    description=null;
    layout=null;
    itsAt=null;
    itIs=null;
}
```

Whenever I open an Item and close it, when I do it again, it just opens more ram, until I have over half of a gig invested in this program.

EDIT:
I took a heap dump, (granted I am new to them), and it showed this:

```
One instance of "java.nio.HeapByteBuffer" loaded by "<system class loader>" occupies 52,633,864 (87.66%) bytes. The instance is referenced by Manager.ItemWindowController @ 0xc51ea6f8 , loaded by "sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader @ 0xc1f45008". The memory is accumulated in one instance of "byte[]" loaded by "<system class loader>".

Keywords
byte[]
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader @ 0xc1f45008
java.nio.HeapByteBuffer
```

And going further in, there is a byte[] using 52,633,816 on the heap whose value is "...................................................."(etc)

Comment: Have you taken a heap dump?  What has that told you?

Comment: Also, the Exceptions it is calling in the console are beyond me. They aren't hindering anything, but they are still there. So I just let them be for now.

Comment: Oh, by the way, we don't do OneDrive links here.  Those links can break, which makes this question useless to future readers.  Everything I need to answer the question should be in the question itself without me having to click on any links.

Comment: No. Let me look into that.

Comment: OK. I'll fix the 1drv link.